# pandas groupby id and find maximum repeated weekday

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

sample of data looks like this :

```
    id  week_day
0   48  Wednesday
1   48  Wednesday
2   51  Saturday
3   53  Friday
4   54  Tuesday
5   56  Thursday
6   57  Wednesday
7   57  Thursday
8   57  Thursday
9   58  Thursday
10  60  Monday
11  60  Monday
12  60  Tuesday
13  60  Wednesday
14  62  Monday
15  62  Wednesday
16  62  Thursday
17  62  Thursday
18  62  Saturday
19  62  Saturday
```

I want to find the for each id the weekday that is repeated maximum number of times(in case of clash randomly any week can be considered).
So I used

```
function(df):
    return pd.Series({'frequent_weeday':df['booked_day'].max()}]
df.groupby('id').apply(function)
```

The output is

```
    frequent_week_day
id  
48  2014-09-10
51  2014-09-06
53  2014-09-12
54  2014-09-09
56  2014-09-11
57  2014-09-10
58  2014-09-11
60  2014-09-10
62  2014-09-10
63  2014-09-09
64  2014-09-11
```

which is asurdly unexpected.

Can you help me find the most frequent weekday for each id in the dataset?

+1 if you have figured out how pandas is interpreting and shows "useless" values as output and doesnt give an error.

Thanks very much for any insight you may have!

Comment: Your code works for me: `
Out[11]:
   frequent_weeday
id                
48       Wednesday
51        Saturday
53          Friday
54         Tuesday
56        Thursday
57       Wednesday
58        Thursday
60       Wednesday
62       Wednesday` what version pandas are you running and what are the dtypes of the week day column?

Comment: But 62 should be thursday, or saturday no? The frequency is needed, not the string max...

Comment: Name: week_day, Length: 389412, dtype: object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been on holiday for a month, and brain not quite functioning properly. If i understand you correctly you want for each ID the weekday that appears most frequently. Given the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id'           : [ 48, 48, 51, 53, 54, 56,  57,  57,  57,  58, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
                       62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62],
        'booked_day' : [ 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Tuesday', 
                     'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 
                     'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday', 
                     'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday']}
DF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I get the solution I think you want by doing this:

```
DF.groupby('id').agg(lambda x : x.booked_day.value_counts().index[0])

   booked_day
id
48  Wednesday
51   Saturday
53     Friday
54    Tuesday
56   Thursday
57   Thursday
58   Thursday
60     Monday
62   Thursday
```